maping info with transaction hash
I need some help with a solana project. So I am building a DAO voting platform with blinks and the proposal part is already done but I am not able to store the proposal on chain. I have 2 sections in the proposal title and description I need to map them with the tx hash so that I can create a voting blink using that hash
It is for the DSCVR hackathon. Can you please help me ?
